# What do you call dice with more than 6 sides?

Tags: single-word-requests

For a *die* in board games, there is the word *ĵetkubo*. However not all dice are cubes, since 16-sided or 32-sided dice exist. What do you call these kinds of dice?

Answer (score 4):

If you are bothered by the *kubo* part, just say *ĵetaĵo*, "throw-thing, projectile".

*Ĵetpluredro* is the most correct but might sound a bit pedantic.

The adjective can be *4-faca, 4-edra, 4-flanka* (but not really *4-surfaca*).

Comment: Would not _ĵetaĵo_ be understood as _projectile_ from most people?

Comment: A die is a projectile.

Comment: The OP is asking for _dice_, not _projectile_.

Comment: A die is a variety of projectile. Therefore, *20-edra ĵetaĵo* is acceptable if he wants to avoid *kubo*.

Comment: Do you meant it is a projectile because it is thrown? Also a rock would be a projectile, in that case. That is why I asked if people would not think to a projectile, and not a dice used for board games.

Comment: Yes, dice are projectiles because they are thrown. The D&D-player may be able to guess in context that a *20-edra ĵetaĵo* is a 20-sided die and not a 20-sided rock or dart or baseball. Outside that context, *ĵetpluredro* would be a better choice, if the OP objects to *kubo*.

Comment: Actually, it would be a projectile when used as weapon.

Comment: Okay, on rereading these comments I see the problem. A *projectile* can refer, especially in physics, to any object which is projected (shot or thrown) for any purpose. The military usage is derived from that. Both *projectile* and *missile* are as close as you can get in English to a single-word equivalent of *ĵetitaĵo*, and they both have a more specific meaning in military contexts, usually rendered in Esperanto as *pafaĵo*.

Comment: I hope I didn't sound harsh in any way. I was trying to make clear the answer to users who know English more than Esperanto. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 2):

This [translation of the rules of D&D](http://drakoj.ikso.net/) just calls them for example *20-flanka kubeto*. I guess they decided to ignore the inconsistency because if they made a word without *kub-* in it it would be harder to understand.

In English it is common to use abbreviations like *d20* and this rulebook seems to use *k20*.

Answer (score 1):

First thing coming to mind for me is *32-flanka ĵetkubo*.

Otherwise, possibly...*32-surfaca ĵetkubo*?

Edit: Ah, I see, you mean using something other than "kubo". I'll edit this again after thinking about that.

Edit: **pluredro** is the word for "polyhedron", so perhaps 32-flanka ĵetpluredro (or ludpluredro?) is going to be a more accurate option. But I don't think people would become terribly confused by the word ĵetkubo plus the number of sides it has, since the intention of that is (probably) easily understood even if it's not quite logical. People probably aren't as familiar with the word pluredro.